# Acumatica - Need underscores in my email addresses

Tags: acumatica

I have a field in my customization that I've set to [PXDBEmail]  Unfortunately, this field replaces entered underscores with a space.  Is there a way to keep it from doing so?

**Update - DAC code below**

```
    public abstract class customerID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected string _CustomerID;

    [PXDBEmail]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "User Name")]
    public virtual string CustomerID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._CustomerID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._CustomerID = value != null ? value.Trim() :null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tested PXDBEmail and it accepted an underscore. Can you include the DAC Field you are using in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my ASPX had a PXMaskEdit field instead of a PXTextEdit Field.  Strange one!
Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, the Email field on the Customers screen accept undercores without any issues:
[image]

Could you please compare the decalration of your custom field with the declaration of the EMail field from the Contact DAC?

```
public partial class Contact : IBqlTable, IContactBase, IAssign, IPXSelectable, CRDefaultMailToAttribute.IEmailMessageTarget
{
    ...
    #region EMail
    public abstract class eMail : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
    private string _eMail;

    [PXDBEmail]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Email", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    [PXMassMergableField]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    public virtual String EMail
    {
        get { return _eMail; }
        set { _eMail = value != null ? value.Trim() : null; }
    }

    #endregion
    ...
}
```